# Command substitution in PS1 doesn't update when it should; cached output?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to add branch name on terminal's prompt like `user@host:directory [branch]`. I tried two codes and found that Code.2 doesn't work as I expected; branch name isn't reflected when checking out another branch. It seems like bash is caching previous command's result.

Could somebody please tell me what's Code.2's problem? I also want to know what does `\` before `$()` means?

## Environment

- macOS 10.14.3
- git 2.19.2

## Code.1 - it works

```
user@host:directory [master]$ cat ~/.bashrc
PS1="\u@\h:\W \$(git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/[\1]/')\$ "
user@host:directory [master]$ git checkout another-branch
user@host:directory [another-branch]$ 
user@host:directory [another-branch]$ git checkout master
user@host:directory [master]$
```

## Code.2 - it fails

```
user@host:directory [master]$ cat ~/.bashrc
BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/[\1]/')
PS1="\u@\h:\W ${BRANCH_NAME}\$ "
user@host:directory [master]$ git checkout another-branch
user@host:directory [master]$ 
user@host:directory [master]$ git checkout master
user@host:directory [master]$
```

Comment: Code.1 works since the branch name is evaluated at every line on bash, where as in the Code.2 you are passing an evaluated variable name and it stays the same in `PS1`

Comment: Definitively @ViKiG is right. PS1, and only PS1, is evaluated each time the prompt is displayed.

Comment: ...and one more thing: NO, bash never caches results!

Comment: (it's not silent "caching"; what you're doing is *explicit* assignment of a specific point-in-time's results!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with Git—it's purely a question of doing the desired operations in bash itself.

Bash has five variables named `PS0`, `PS1`, `PS2`, `PS3`, and `PS4` that are [described in the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) this way:

> [**PS0**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS0)
> The value of this parameter is expanded like `PS1` and displayed by interactive shells after reading a command and before the command is executed.
>
> [**PS1**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS1)
> The primary prompt string. The default value is `‘\s-\v\$ ’`. See [Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt), for the complete list of escape sequences that are expanded before `PS1` is displayed.
>
> **PS2**
> The secondary prompt string. The default value is `‘> ’`. `PS2` is expanded in the same way as `PS1` before being displayed.
>
> **PS3**
> The value of this variable is used as the prompt for the `select` command. If this variable is not set, the select command prompts with `‘#? ’`
>
> **PS4**
> The value of this parameter is expanded like `PS1` and the expanded value is the prompt printed before the command line is echoed when the `-x` option is set (see [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)). The first character of the expanded value is replicated multiple times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indirection. The default is `‘+ ’`.

The tricky part here is that `PS1` is *evaluated by expansion* before printing the prompt.  This evaluation has a lot of magic escape sequences, all described in the [linked section about controlling the prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt).  Then, as the documentation says:

> After the string is decoded, it is expanded via parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal, subject to the value of the `promptvars` shell option (see [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)).

The *command substitution* part is important in the setting that works (the first `.bashrc`, which you called Code.1).  That bashrc reads, in part:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\W \$(git branch)\$ "
```

(I've shortened this to take out a lot of it to make explaining it easier).  This line is evaluated once when bash sources this bashrc, so each element inside the double quotes is subject to parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal *at this time*.  The result of all of that is to leave `PS1` set to:

```
\u@\h:\W $(git branch)$
```

(there is a space at the end of the line above).

Now bash *evaluates PS1 again* each time it is about to print a prompt.  This *second* (but repeated) evaluation decodes `\u`, `\H`, and `\W`, leaving the shell with:

```
user@host:directory $(git branch) $
```

This sequence now undergoes

> parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal

*again*, and *this* time, `$(git branch)` produces a command-substitution result.  (This would read `master` or `another-branch` without square brackets; the `sed` that I dropped takes care of those.)

The "Code.2" version of a bashrc reads in part:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\W ${BRANCH_NAME}\$ "
```

which undergoes the usual rules once during the reading of that bashrc itself, leaving behind:

```
\u@\h:\W [master]$
```

(again there is a space at the end) as the value stored in `PS1`.  This value is "decoded [and] expanded" again before reading each command, but this time, there is no command to run as part of command substitution.  The literal text `[master]` is embedded in the value.